# TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len() Python random.shuffle(param) error

Tags: python, python-3.7, shuffle

```
 import random
 import math
 import time
 import csv

 class AIRS:

   """AIRS (Artificial Immune Recognition System) class
 Main class for this algorithm

Params:
    hyper_clonal_rate (float) : Define the number of clones an ARB is allowed to produce
    
    clonal_rate (float) : Define the number of ressources an ARB can obtain
    
    class_number (int) : The number of classes (3 in this case)
    mc_init_rate (float) : Define the number of training data to be copied in memory cells
   
    total_num_resources (float) : The total numbers of resources to share between ARBs
    
    affinity_threshold_scalar  (float) : Give a cut-off value for cell replacement
    
    k (int) : The number of memory cells to use for classification
    
    test_size (float) : The percentage of global data to take as test data
"""

def __init__(self, hyper_clonal_rate, clonal_rate, class_number, mc_init_rate,
             total_num_resources, affinity_threshold_scalar, k, test_size):
    
    self.HYPER_CLONAL_RATE = hyper_clonal_rate        
    self.CLONAL_RATE = clonal_rate        
    self.AFFINITY_THRESHOLD = 0        
    self.CLASS_NUMBER = class_number        
    self.MC_INIT_RATE = mc_init_rate       
    self.TOTAL_NUM_RESOURCES = total_num_resources        
    self.AFFINITY_THRESHOLD_SCALAR = affinity_threshold_scalar        
    self.TEST_SIZE = test_size        
    self.K = k        
    self.MC = None        
    self.AB = None

@staticmethod
def affinity(vector1, vector2):
    """Compute the affinity (Normalized !! distance) between two features vectors
    :param vector1: First features vector
    :param vector2: Second features vector
    :return: The affinity between the two vectors [0-1]
    """

    d = 0
    for i, j in zip(vector1, vector2):
        d += (i - j) ** 2
    euclidian_distance = math.sqrt(d)
    return euclidian_distance / (1 + euclidian_distance)

def train_test_split(self):
    with open("/Users/user_name/Downloads/iris.data", "r") as data:
        content = data.readlines()
        ret = (((float(x.split[","][i]) for i in range(4)), mapping(x.split[","][4][:-1])) for x in content)
        random.seed()
        random.shuffle(ret)
    return ret[:int((1 - self.TEST_SIZE) * len(ret))], ret[int((1 - self.TEST_SIZE) * len(ret)):]
```

**When I run these code, I got a error like this**

```
  File "/Users/user_name/.spyder-py3/AIRS.py", line 67, in train_test_split
    random.shuffle(ret)

  File "/Users/user_name/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/random.py", line 275, in shuffle
    for i in reversed(range(1, len(x))):

TypeError: object of type 'generator' has no len()
```

Could anybody help me please? Cause I didn't understand what I should do.

NOTE: I cloned this code from https://github.com/AghilesAzzoug/Artificial-Immune-System/blob/master/main.py

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. The error is telling you that `ret` is a generator, not a sequence as the [random docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.shuffle) state are required for `random.shuffle`. You need to make the generator into a list for shuffle to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working of `range` has changed over the years.  It originally returned a `list`, now it returns a generator.  Just turn the generator into a list.

```
ret = list(ret)
random.shuffle(ret)
```